# Can I use a hook other than 'init' to handle form submissions?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, forms, init

I'm developing a plugin that handles form submissions at several different points. As such, I was relying on being able to use `global $post` and `get_query_var` to determine which stage the user is at and handle the submission & redirect accordingly. However, it's become apparent that neither `$post` nor `get_query_var` are available at the point `init` is fired (which is when I've always hooked in for standard form submissions before, and everything I can find online recommends the same).

Without seriously rethinking this whole thing, can I hook into a different, later action (for example `wp`) to process the form submission and access the required variables? Is there any issue with hooking into a later action like this?

I'm aware that hooking into `wp-head` is too late if I want to use `wp_redirect`, and I guess I'd need to hook in to something either at or after `parse_request` to get access to `get_query_vars()`?

Comment: I would look into the `template_redirect` hook

Comment: @czerspalace Thanks - for the moment I've gone with the `wp` hook - any particular reason to choose one over the other? Or just dealer's choice?